# How to retain <script> tag while setting html

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am doing some AJAX call which returns plain HTML with some javascript code.While i set returned response to container using .html (Jquery) or innerHTML (plain javascript) it removes  tag and all javascript.

But when I change `<script type="text/javascript">` to `<script type="text/xml">` it retains all script tags and javascript. But my script does not execute even no alert and congole.log work inside this.

Please suggest me if i can retain  tag and javascript without changing type.

Thanks

Comment: can you add your code?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem before by changing my AJAX call from a `GET` to a `POST`.

Comment: Hi Changing AJAX call from GET to POST will not make any difference. I am getting <script> tags in response. They are removed after setting innerHTML to a container.